# Is there any difference between knowledge and information?

Tags: knowledge

I am confused about find difference between knowledge and information. Give me an example.

Comment: What are your researches so far?

Comment: I have not done any researches, but I have read lots of books on culture,  tradition, philosophy.

Comment: Read this, and not only. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge

Comment: See e.g. [Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information): "Information is any entity or form that resolves uncertainty or provides the answer to a question of some kind. It is thus related to data and knowledge, as data represents values attributed to parameters, and knowledge signifies understanding of real things or abstract concepts. As it regards data, the information's existence is not necessarily coupled to an observer (it exists beyond an event horizon, for example), while in the case of knowledge, the information requires a cognitive observer."

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you refer to. The can be closer or far apart as a concept.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information), and then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge).

As an example, lets take this string `0001 1100`.

The **information** is the answer of "What is this?". This is a *string of bits*.

The **knowledge** is the answer of "Do I understand what is a string of bits?(do I understand the information)". By the way, the best way to check if you have knowledge about something is to *explain* to someone who has no idea about it. If he understands it right, then you understood it right.

And as a bonus, **wisdom** is the way you materialize your knowledge by putting it into practice. In our example, the wisdom is the fact the you know not only what is a string of bits, but how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither 'knowledge' nor 'information' has a fixed, distinct, single meaning. But I think the most fruitful approach is to regard them, not as mutually exclusive, nor as identical but as points or stages on a continuum.

▻ IDENTITY

Someone might say, 'I want to know what's happening, just give me the information'. Here the terms appear to be used synonymously. There's nothing wrong with this but I think it fails to bring out some latent distinctions.

▻  MUTUAL EXCLUSIVITY

On this view, information is just data, discrete and disconnected. Merely having information doesn't help you understand anything. For instance, if someone gives me the information, 'A circle's radius, circumference and area are closely linked to the definition of the constant π', I accept this as information but it does not explain what this close linkage is or even tell me what e.g. 'radius' and 'circumference' mean, let alone 'the constant π'. It would be in order to refer politely to my ignorance but even to a professional mathematician it is not knowledge, only (unnecessary) information. He or she receives information but does not gain knowledge. What is received does not add to their knowledge or enable them to understand anything not understood before. It is just (useless) information.

▻ CONTINUITY

If information is data, discrete and disconnected, it is most usefully seen, I think, as a point on a continuum on which knowledge is located too. Informational data is the growth-point of knowledge. As data is collated, connected, one item related to another, so it is systematised and synthesised into a body of knowledge where knowledge is an integrated model of some area of inquiry or activity, a model that enables and supports description, explanation and prediction.

Comment: To forestall the all too common objections to this kind of question and answer, (a) I am not prescribing the 'proper' use of terms and (b) I am not providing an answer where a dictionary would serve. I am suggesting what I take to be useful conceptual distinctions between 'knowledge' and 'information'. Concepts (their analysis and distinction) are, I assume, a part of the business of philosophers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between knowledge and information. But in usage there is a huge difference,that is- when you got information, then that is knowledge.Information is got by u , called knowledge